# Width (-1) and Height (-1) cannot be <= 0

Tags: java, macos, processing

I keep getting some weird error in Processing, using the following tiny piece of code:

```
void setup() {
  size(200,200);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  loadPixels();
  updatePixels();
}
```

The error: (with stack trace)

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (-1) and height (-1) cannot be <= 0
    at java.awt.image.DirectColorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(DirectColorModel.java:1016)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.<init>(BufferedImage.java:357)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CImage$Creator.createFromImage(CImage.java:101)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CPlatformWindow.getImageForTarget(CPlatformWindow.java:693)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CPlatformWindow.updateIconImages(CPlatformWindow.java:519)
    at sun.lwawt.macosx.CPlatformWindow.setVisible(CPlatformWindow.java:484)
    at sun.lwawt.LWWindowPeer$1.run(LWWindowPeer.java:260)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:240)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:142)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:134)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Now at first I thought this was a bug, because there previously was another bug that disappeared when I restarted Processing. It seems it still doesn't have good Mac OS X Lion support (that's what I'm using). But I tried both the stable release and the prerelease and both have the same error. Has anyone else gotten this? Does anyone know how to fix it? Do I need to install a better JDK or something?

Comment: Please show the stack trace for the exception.

Comment: And what do `background`, `loadPixels` and `updatePixels` do? It would help if you could show us a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem...

Comment: That is a complete program, in the language called Processing. http://processing.org/ It's basically Java with some convenience wrappers. Those functions are supposedly "built-in".

Comment: Fair enough - in that case I think you're less likely to get an answer, as it's Processing-specific :(

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'll just wait and see if I'm lucky and someone who happens to have experience in Processing stumbles upon this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough it started working fine after a couple of restarts. It's weird and I don't know why it behaved like that. Anyways, it works now.

Answer (score 2):

See the example for loadPixels: http://processing.org/reference/loadPixels_.html

I think you need image data to be in the sketch before you can load it into an array from the display window.

Try adding an image and see what happens.